# Wordpress: count time from registration date to today

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I would like to add to the user profile the time from registration to the current day in the format:

> With us: 7 years 3 months 2 weeks 6 days

OR

> With us: 1 year 1 month 1 week 1 day

Me a bit helped this post Count days from registration date to today, but there countdown goes only in days.

Comment: How are you storing their registration time? It may be helpful if you share some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that

```php
    $today_date      = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'today' ) ) );
    $register_date  = get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', get_current_user_id() );
    $registered = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $register_date ) ) );
    $interval_date   = $today_date->diff( $registered );
        if( $interval_date->days < 31 ) {
            echo 'With us ' . $interval_date->format('%d days');
            }
        elseif( $interval_date->days < 365 ) {
            echo 'With us ' . $interval_date->format('%m months %d days');
            }
        elseif( $interval_date->days > 365 ) {
            echo 'With us ' . $interval_date->format('%y years %m month %d days');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime(get_userdata(get_current_user_id( ))->user_registered)) to get register date, After you compare with time() to get number year, month, day.